# Angular Htpp Post to Json shows [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-http

i need help about my personal project. I'm trying to use Angular HTTP post method then i got this kind of bug. When i add new data, call `addStudent`, and reload the page, the `semester` columns return/show `[object Object]`. Other Columns are working correctly except for `semester`.

```js
//file name: app.service.ts
 addStudent(newId: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newScore: string): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/Student", {id: newId, name: newName, year: newYear, semester: newSemester, score: newScore});
    }
```

```js
//file name : app.component.ts
addStudent(newId: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newScore: string)
  {
    this.stockService.addStudent(newId, newName, newYear, newSemester, newScore).subscribe();
    console.log(newSemester);
  }
```

```html
<!--file name: app.component.html-->
<tr *ngFor="let Student of Student" [attr.id]="Student.id">
    <td>{{Student.id}}</td> 
    <td>{{Student.name}}</td>
    <td>{{Student.year}}</td>
    <td>{{Student.semester}}</td>
    <td>{{Student.score}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</h1>

<h3>ADD NEW</h3>
<br>ID: <input #newId/>
<br>Name: <input #newName/>
<br>Year: <input #newYear/>
<br>Semester: <input #newSemester/>
<br>Score: <input #newScore/>
<br><button type="button" role="button" (click)="addStudent(newId.value, newName.value, newYear.value, newSemester, newScore.value)">ADD</button>
```

the Json looks like this when added new row

`{
    "id": "a",
    "name": "a",
    "year": "a",
    "semester": {},
    "score": "a"
}`

Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just typo.

```
<button type="button" role="button" (click)="addStudent(newId.value, newName.value, newYear.value, newSemester, newScore.value)">ADD</button>
```

See you forgot **.value** for newSemester.

Change to:

```
<button type="button" role="button" (click)="addStudent(newId.value, newName.value, newYear.value, newSemester.value, newScore.value)">ADD</button>
```

Comment: I carelessly forgot to type `.value` . What a silly problem. Thank you very much anyway :)